# Setting variable A with name stored in variable B

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have the following two variables:

```
a = 1;
b = 'a';
```

I want to be able to do

```
SOMETYPEOFEVALUATION(b) = 2;
```

so that the value of variable `a` is now set to `2`.

```
a # => 2
```

Is this possible?

Specifically, I am working with the Facebook API. Each object has a variety of different connections (friends, likes, movies, etc). I have a parser class that stores the state of the last call to the Facebook API for all of these connections. These states are all named corresponding to the the GET you have to call in order to update them.

For example, to update the Music connection, you use https://graph.facebook.com/me/music?access_token=... I store the result in a variable called updated_music. For books, its updated_books. If I created a list of all these connection type names, I ideally want to do something like this.

```
def update_all
  connection_list.each do |connection_name|
    updated_SomeTypeOfEvalAndConcatenation(connection_name) = CallToAPI("https://graph.facebook.com/me/#{connection_name}?access_token=...")
    end
end
```

Very new to both Rails and StackOverflow so please let me know if there is a better way to follow any conventions.

Tried the below.

```
class FacebookParser

attr_accessor   :last_albums_json,         

  def update_parser_vars(service)
     handler = FacebookAPIHandler.new
     connections_type_list = ['albums']
     connections_type_list.each do |connection_name|
       eval "self.last_#{connection_name}_json = handler.access_api_by_content_type(service, #{connection_name})['data']"
     end
    #self.last_albums_json = handler.access_api_by_content_type(service, 'albums')['data']
   end


 end
```

And I get this error

```
undefined local variable or method `albums' for #<FacebookParser:0xaa7d12c>
```

Works fine when I use line that is commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
eval "#{b}=2"
```

and with instance variables you can also do `instance_variable_set("@name", value)`

EDIT:

you can also use `send` method if you have a setter defined(and you have), try this:

```
class FacebookParser
  attr_accessor   :last_albums_json,         

  def update_parser_vars(service)
    handler = FacebookAPIHandler.new
     connections_type_list = ['albums']
     connections_type_list.each do |connection_name|
       send("last_#{connection_name}_json=", 
         handler.access_api_by_content_type(
           service, connection_name)['data']))
     end
  end
end
```

problem with your original code is that

```
eval ".... handler.access_api_by_content_type(service, #{connection_name})"
```

would execute

```
... handler.access_api_by_content_type(service, albums)
# instead of
... handler.access_api_by_content_type(service, 'albums')
```

so you had to write

```
eval ".... handler.access_api_by_content_type(service, '#{connection_name}')" <- the quotes!
```

this is why people usually avoid using eval - it's easy to do this kind of mistakes

Comment: `instance_variable_set` , not `set_instance_variable`

Comment: updated, and btw you *can* use instance_variable_set in your code, as attr_accessor is basically generating getter/setter for instance variable

Answer (score 3):

Changing an unrelated variable like that is a bit of a code smell;  Most programmers don't like it when a variable magically changes value, at least not without being inside an enclosing class.

In that simple example, it's much more common to say:

```
a=something(b)
```

Or if a is a more complex thing, make it a class:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor  :a

  def initialize(value)
    @a = value
  end

  def transform(value)
    @a = "new value: #{value}"
  end
end

baz = "something"
bar = Foo.new(2)
bar.a
=> 2
bar.transform(baz)
bar.a
=> "new value: something"
```

So while the second example changes an internal variable but not through the accessor, at least it is part of an encapsulated object with a limited API.

**Update** Ah, I think the question is how do do like php's [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). As mu suggests, if you want to do this, you are probably doing the wrong thing... it's a concept that should never have been thought of. Use classes or hashes or something.

Comment: Don't see how to make a useful class in this situation. I could put all of the variables into a new class, say, "ParserVars" but it would still need a set of if statements inside to match a passed in argument with one of the variables. To be clear, having to use all of those if statements is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @user1114840 just take look at your variable and you can instantly say there's too much stuff going on - *last*_*albums*_*json*, check if you could refactor that into more concise code like having only `albums` as your object which would then provide `albums.last` which then could be converted to json by doing `albums.last.to_json` - that's a lot of reusability right there!

Answer (score 0):

These sort of things are not usually done using local variables and their names in Ruby. A usual approach could include hashes and symbols:

```
data = Hash.new
data[:a] = 1 # a = 1
b = :a       # b = 'a'
```

and then, later

```
data[b] = 2  # SOMETYPEOFEVALUATION(b) = 2
data[:a]     # => 2
```